# Why does iTunes repeatedly start playing

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, television

Whenever I plug my 13" MacBook Pro into my TV (via DVI) iTunes spontaneously starts playing.  If I quit it, it reopens and starts playing again.  I ended up having to rename iTunes.app to get it to stop.

Comment: I just thought of something; I'm using the headphone jack to connect audio; could something on that end up being interpreted as a "play" command from a headset?

Comment: Has this always happened, or did it just recently start?

Comment: Open Console.app before you plug the MacBook in, plug it in, and watch if messages appear in the `All Messages` section of Console.app. This might give you a pointer on what process is causing this.